# Sporadic problems with some images

Tags: apache, images

I have a website http://dermadoc.ch with several images that are no more displayed (mostly by IE versions)

My server shows no errors but the browser just displays the broken image symbol.

The images seem fine, for example http://dermadoc.ch/images/canfield.jpg

```
$ identify canfield.jpg
canfield.jpg JPEG 153x115 153x115+0+0 8-bit sRGB 5.55KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

browsershots.org shows no problem with any version, but I have some IE 11 examples where the images are not shown.

It's seems that the problem is intermittent (see comments).

The files were not modified since ages and I don't remember any relevant changes in the Apache config but the inclusion of IPv6 Adresses (but this was months ago and the problems are newer).

The corresponding `vhost` definition

```
<VirtualHost 78.47.122.114:80 [2a01:4f8:d13:f44::2]:80>
    ServerAdmin matteo@corti.li

    DocumentRoot /var/www/dermadoc.ch/

    RequestHeader unset If-Modified-Since
    RequestHeader unset If-None-Match

   <IfModule mod_headers.c>
     <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz|html)$">
        Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
      </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>

    <Directory /var/www/dermadoc.ch/>
       Options +Includes
       AllowOverride AuthConfig       
     </Directory>

    ServerName dermadoc.ch
    ServerAlias www.dermadoc.ch
    ErrorLog logs/dermadoc.ch-error_log
    CustomLog logs/dermadoc.ch-access_log combined

    XBitHack on

</VirtualHost>
```

Some images are displayed as "broken", most likely only partially transmitted.

Are there some global settings that could have been changed by an Apache update?
Are there known problem with latest updates on Fedora?

**Update**

Looking at the log entries I notice that the size of the object varies greatly (from 1KB to 5KB for the very same file)

Why does Apache deliver different content for the same file?

For the file in my example (the first number is the number of entries in the log and the second the size):

```
  1 1150
  8 5472
 11 5500
142 5549
```

**Update 2**

Completely removed `mod_deflate.so`. No improvements

**Update 3**

The delivered headers seems OK (with the correct size 5500)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 24 Mar 2016 17:13:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Fedora) OpenSSL/1.0.2g-fips PHP/5.6.19 SVN/1.9.3 mod_wsgi/4.4.8 Python/2.7.10
Last-Modified: Thu, 24 Mar 2016 13:58:14 GMT
ETag: "157c-52ecbd675dda8"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 5500
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Comment: @SimonHayter I was able to reproduce it on at least 7 machines with a mix of Windows and IE versions.

Comment: Well I investigated the problem further... seems this problem is not just isolated to IE... http://dermadoc.ch/images/StarLux300-ipl-opl-laser_170x.png is missing in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Safari never shows the problem. Firefox is OK but the mobile version on iOS also does not show many pictures.  I really don't know what could be the problem

Comment: `This image cannot be displayed, because it contains errors`... appears that your images are corrupt, some browsers and versions may be more sensitive to the problem than others.

Comment: I recommend that you replace all those images with placeholders.

Comment: The image @SimonHayter points to is not being served as an image and its mime type is incorrect but this is off topic here.

Comment: http://dermadoc.ch/images/StarLux300-ipl-opl-laser_170x.png Now works, strangely enough.  I suppose you reuploaded the file?

Comment: @Rob, MIME type wouldn't effect testing the file locally, i.e photoshop.

Comment: @SimonHayter And photoshop has nothing to do with the web. His image was not served as image/png. That is the problem. This is a software or server config issue.

Comment: `http://dermadoc.ch/images/canfield.jpg` is being served as a  
`image/jpeg`

Comment: Yes it is. And the problem is intermittent. It's a server config or, more likely, software issue.

Comment: Rob the file isn't a valid PNG... setting the MIME type with a broken file won't magically FIX a broken file now will it... Photoshop or not, various other programs find problems with it.

Comment: Since the png image intermittently works, it must be something other than the image. Observing the network in the browser shows it is not being served properly. There is no mime type at all.

Comment: I unable 'not to get the image to work', and the MIME hasn't changed. I agree if he/she hasn't replaced the image then its a software/network issue.

Comment: But either way, with the information provided its impossible to know what the issue exactly is. @Matteo if the problem can be narrowed down to an issue with the virtual host, and apache conf then we may be able to assist on Pro Webmasters but we will need more information, if the problem can be narrowed down to a networking or server fault, then it'll be best suited on the Server Fault Stack, let us know.

Comment: As I didn't change the files in at least a year the only thing that could be different is the Apache version or the config but also there no changes on my side

Answer (score 1):

Your images are likely corrupt and one of the reason why some browsers or versions may work is because they may use a different imaging process that chooses to ignore the issue.

*The image `StarLux300-ipl-opl-laser_170x.png` fails to load in:*

- Firefox v40.06b
- Chrome V49.0.2623.87 m
- IE/Edge v25.10586.0.0
- Opera v11.60 Build 1185

*Downloading the image and testing locally in Adobe Photoshop:*

[image: adobe photoshop cc 2014 could not complete your request because the file format module cannot parse the file]

*Solution: Replace your broken images with ones that are not broken.*

Comment: A couple of links that may help scan for corrupt ones: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401527/how-do-i-programmatically-check-whether-an-image-png-jpeg-or-gif-is-corrupte and https://superuser.com/questions/276154/automating-the-scanning-of-graphics-files-for-corruption